# Spreading text in table over multiple rows

Tags: tables, multirow, text

I have a problem when placing two  tables side by side using minipage, the tables are bigger than half a pagewidth however they could be reduced in size if I place the text 'Leading Tail' in two rows except I have no idea how to do this.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}

        \begin{tabular}{ll|lll}
            &                   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Trailing Radius}} \\
            &                   & \textbf{R68}  & \textbf{R34}  & \textbf{R17} \\ \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Leading Tail}} & \textbf{No Tail}  & 0.389         & 0.404         & 0.426        \\
            & \textbf{6° Tail}  & 0.416         & 0.425         & 0.439        \\
            & \textbf{12° Tail} & 0.379         & 0.394         & 0.415        \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}

    \begin{tabular}{ll|lll}
        &                   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Trailing Radius}} \\
        &                   & \textbf{R68}  & \textbf{R34}  & \textbf{R17} \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Leading Tail}} & \textbf{No Tail}  & 0.389         & 0.404         & 0.426        \\
        & \textbf{6° Tail}  & 0.416         & 0.425         & 0.439        \\
        & \textbf{12° Tail} & 0.379         & 0.394         & 0.415        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

[image: Result of above code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `\multirowcell` command from the `makecell` package as shown in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
 \begin{tabular}{ll|lll}
    &                   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Trailing Radius}} \\
    &                   & \textbf{R68}  & \textbf{R34}  & \textbf{R17} \\ \hline
    \textbf{\multirowcell{3}[0pt][l]{Leading \\ Tail}} & \textbf{No Tail}  & 0.389       & 0.404       & 0.426        \\
    & \textbf{6° Tail}  & 0.416         & 0.425         & 0.439        \\
    & \textbf{12° Tail} & 0.379         & 0.394         & 0.415        \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
 \begin{tabular}{ll|lll}
    &                   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Trailing Radius}} \\
    &                   & \textbf{R68}  & \textbf{R34}  & \textbf{R17} \\ \hline
    \textbf{\multirowcell{3}[0pt][l]{Leading \\ Tail}} & \textbf{No Tail}  & 0.389       & 0.404       & 0.426        \\
    & \textbf{6° Tail}  & 0.416         & 0.425         & 0.439        \\
    & \textbf{12° Tail} & 0.379         & 0.394         & 0.415        \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Please keep in mind that since you didn't provide the documentclass you are using, nor information about the margin sizes, the tables still do not fit within the textwidth in the above MWE.

Answer (score 2):

i would set your table on the following way:

[image]

or

[image]

for the first case the document example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\bfseries}p{9ex} lll}
    \toprule
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Trailing Radius}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\multirow{-2}{=}{Leading\\ Tail}
            & \textbf{R68}  & \textbf{R34}  & \textbf{R17} \\ 
    \hline
No Tail     & 0.389         & 0.404         & 0.426        \\
6° Tail     & 0.416         & 0.425         & 0.439        \\
12° Tail    & 0.379         & 0.394         & 0.415        \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\bfseries}p{9ex} lll}
    \toprule
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Trailing Radius}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\multirow{-2}{=}{Leading\\ Tail}
            & \textbf{R68}  & \textbf{R34}  & \textbf{R17} \\
    \hline
No Tail     & 0.389         & 0.404         & 0.426        \\
6° Tail     & 0.416         & 0.425         & 0.439        \\
12° Tail    & 0.379         & 0.394         & 0.415        \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

for the second case you need onla replace `\hfill` between tables with `%`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different design using `booktabs` and only `multirow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l lll@{}}
            \multirow{2}{*}[-2pt]{\textbf{Leading Tail}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Trailing Radius}} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-4} 
                                                         & \textbf{R68} & \textbf{R34} & \textbf{R17}   \\ \toprule
            No Tail                                      & 0.389        & 0.404        & 0.426          \\
            6° Tail                                      & 0.416        & 0.425        & 0.439          \\
            12° Tail                                     & 0.379        & 0.394        & 0.415          \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l lll@{}}
            \multirow{2}{*}[-2pt]{\textbf{Leading Tail}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Trailing Radius}} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-4}
                                                         & \textbf{R68} & \textbf{R34} & \textbf{R17}   \\ \toprule
            No Tail                                      & 0.389        & 0.404        & 0.426          \\
            6° Tail                                      & 0.416        & 0.425        & 0.439          \\
            12° Tail                                     & 0.379        & 0.394        & 0.415          \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooops, I didn't notice that the question has been answered 4 hrs ago, I should've refreshed my browser!